# Is this kufr? Will Allah forgive me after doing tawbah for kufr?

Tags: sin, punishment, forgiveness, tawba, kufr

Aoa

2 years ago i was interested in reincarnation and Started to think that we could also do reincarnation and stuff and i even tried looking into my past life but i left it since 5 months ago..Alhumdulilah but today i got to know that this is kufr and is this really kufr? And after that i got super depressed..i wanted to cry but i couldn't so what i did was i went to the masjid and i prayed to rakats of salat al tawbah and promised Allah that i will never commit this sin again and i even told it about to my friend but i am so frightened that Allah won't forgive i did tawbah and promised to never return to it please for Allah's sake please tell me did i do good enough? Will Allah forgive me? Jazak Allah

Answer (score 2):

Asalaam Alaikum
first of all i would like to tell you that we muslims do NOT believe in reincarnations, we firmly believe in the Aakhirah. the eternal life after we die. so believing in notions of reincarnation is a sign of lack of faith.

and secondly being afraid that Allah won't forgive you, even after you do a sinciere repentance (tawbah), this is just wrong. the quran and all the authentic teachings of our beloved prophet P.B.U.H, confirms that if we repent before we die from any sin, Allah the mighty and sublime will forgive us. it is also a sign of weak or lack of faith to doubt Allah the mighty and sublime's mercy.

please try to learn the foundations of faith (iman) and increase it. the best way is to start from thawheed. when you have faith, these type of questions and erroneous ways would be avoided. please do reflect and contemplate on the below mentioned verse of the quran, insha Allah you will be guided.

Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."

(chapter 39 verse 53)

Allah knows best.

Comment: Sukran my friend...so even unintentional i mean i intended to do the act but did not intend to do kufr and i did many times will Allah forgive kufr also?

Comment: Please reply....

Comment: Oh and yes i don't believe in reincarnations now...

Comment: So will Allah forgive kufr also?

Comment: Please answer brother

Comment: @MuhammadAli Allah forgives anything if you repent.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Why did you provide two answers when you could edit your answer and rephrase it anytime as a regular user. For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Thank you brother